# Specifying licence on open-graph images?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am building a webpage with open graph tags to make an open-graph object.

When I set the `og:image` tag, is there any way to specify its license?
How other webapps fetching my open-graph object will be aware of its license?
Or these images are thumbnails and considered as public domain and reusable anywhere?

Reciprocally, when I fetch some open-graph objects, can I display images defined in their `og:image` tag on my website?

I have not found the answer on the protocol website http://ogp.me

Comment: I have seen this raised before, I have looked for the post with no luck, the short answer is no.

The bigger scope of this question revolves around the Semantic Web and more importantly the propriety nature of Facebook's implementation. The general idea of the SW is the semantically marked up data organised into ontologies. By marking your data with open graph tags you are allowing it to become part of the SW. There is no licence to this however I interpret that since you added the tags to a publicly available space and made it socially interactive, then therefore the images are public domain.

Comment: You could also argue that the page that contains the open graph tags could have the licence description in the description open graph tag and visibly printed on the page with said image.

Comment: you can follow this on facebook help
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10205971416629429